# Ocaml -> .so -> Golang

Tags: c, go, ocaml, .so

I am a student and I am working on some project in which I need to use code written in ocaml. I want to write a project using Go. To understand how to transfer code from ocaml, I decided to write hello world - application with this code:

`hello.ml`:

```
let print_hello =
  print_endline "Hello World";;

let () =
  Callback.register "Hello callback" print_hello;
;;
```

Next, I used the opam dune to build a shared library (`*.so):

```
$ dune build hello.so
```

According this [topiс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506579/calling-functions-in-an-so-file-from-go), I try to call function from lib with `cgo`:

`main.go`:

```
package main
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*someFunc) ();

void bridge_someFunc(someFunc f) {
    f();
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    libpath := C.CString("./hello.so")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(libpath))
    imglib := C.dlopen(libpath, C.RTLD_LAZY)
    if imglib != nil {
        fHello := C.CString("Hello callback")
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(fHello))
        fp := C.dlsym(imglib, fHello)
        if fp != nil {
            C.bridge_someFunc(C.someFunc(fp))
        }
        C.dlclose(imglib)
    }
}
```

And this not working. What am I doing wrong? Are there other ways?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: expected: Printing Hello, world! Actual: Compiles successfully but doesn’t output anything @JoelBodenmann

Comment: And what is the behavior you're actually experiencing? Where do things go wrong?

Comment: @JoelBodenmann, btw imglib is not nil, but fp is nil. I cannot call this function

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can call an OCaml function directly. See https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#ss:c-closures. tl;dr You need to retrieve the function using `caml_named_value` and call it using `caml_callback`.

Comment: Another issue is that `print_hello` is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just call OCaml functions from C/Go/Rust/any-other-language. OCaml has its own data types and calling convention. Therefore, you need to write some [glue code](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#s:c-callback) that translates C data structures into OCaml and vice verse. This is a non-trivial and error-prone task that requires some experience in OCaml and a deep understanding of OCaml internals. There is a [CTypes](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes) library that enables writing this glue code in OCaml instead of C, which is less error-prone and much easier, but still requires some understanding of OCaml.